# Shape returned by Pandas ValueError does not match the dataframe shape?

Tags: python, pandas

My understanding is `pd.DataFrame().shape`returns **(n_rows, n_columns)**.
However when constructing a dataframe and the indices do not match with the data shape, pandas raises a `ValueError` with the shape as **(n_columns, n_rows)**.

Example:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), index = range(9))
```

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 10), indices imply (2, 9)

**Why does ValueError not print**:

Shape of passed values is (10, 2), indices imply (9, 2)

Pandas Version: '0.17.1'

Answer (score 1):

When pandas says "indices" here it means the index and the columns (they are both of type Index).

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,2))

In [12]: df.index
Out[12]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')

In [13]: df.columns
Out[13]: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

You are passing something with a length 9 `.index` Index, and a length 2 `.columns` Index, hence the error message...
Which is to say: your code is equivalent to:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), index=np.arange(9), columns=np.arange(2))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 10), indices imply (2, 9)
```

When you want is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), index=np.arange(10), colummns=np.arange(2))
# equivalently
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), index=np.arange(10))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I understand why the ValueError is raised. My question is why does it say `Shape of passed values is (2, 10)`. I would think it should read `Shape of passed values is (10, 2)`

Comment: @imp2 ah ha, I see hmm, that's weird. A quick %debug, shows that it's defined here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/a050a331a7fdf87d8c4290a9a1da00dd56f42595/pandas/core/internals.py#L3876-L3883 :s Interesting! If you fancy fixing, I'm sure that'd be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`print range(9)` returns: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, so giving a (10,2) ["10 by 2" array (20 values in two columns of 10)] an index that is a one-dimensional array of 9 values starting at zero won't 'fit' the dimensions of the Numpy array you're converting to a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: My question is not why a ValueError is raised, but was in regards to the explanation in the ValueError.